# In R, how should I compare two data tables and give the desired output as shown below?

Tags: r, data.table

These are just samples of a huge dataframe

```
Sample1
                       col1                            col2
1      123001 124003 125699 348348 3493493 1230404 99930202
2 29238822 293831232 992922 348348 3493493 1230404 99930202
```

Sample1 has set of numbers in each cell(separated by space)

```
Sample2
        col1  col2
1     123001   CAT
2   99930202   PIG
3     124003   ODG
4    1230404 CHAIN
5   29238822   BAT
6  293831232 MOUSE
7    3493493  KIWI
8     125699   JIN
9     992922 ANIME
10    348348  UPPE
```

If a match exists for the numbers in Sample2 table, the corresponding value in Col2 of sample2 table should be pulled up.

A final desired output would be below.

```
Output
                   col1                                col2            col3
1      123001 124003 125699 348348 3493493 1230404 99930202     CAT ODG JIN
2 29238822 293831232 992922 348348 3493493 1230404 99930202 BAT MOUSE ANIME
                 col4
1 UPPE KIWI CHAIN PIG
2 UPPE KIWI CHAIN PIG
```

I have tried using different methods merge, join, sqldf but unable to get my output. Can anyone please help?

Comment: you should generate data frames assigning column name. and also, please explain more on what you intend to do. Moreover, I suggest you to output your data frame Sampl1 and Sample 2. It helps you to understand how they look and frame your Question properly.

Comment: am sorry, modified the question, thank you!

Comment: separator is space

Comment: @d.b if you feel this answers the question, please post it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sample1$col3 = sapply(strsplit(sample1$col1, " "), function(a)
                  paste(sample2$text[match(a, sample2$id)], collapse = " "))
```

If you want to use it on more than one column, then make a function for what we did above and then apply it over the desired columns.

```
myf = function(x){
    return(sapply(strsplit(x, " "), function(a)
        paste(sample2$text[match(a, sample2$id)], collapse = " ")))
}

sapply(sample1, myf)
```

**DATA**

```
sample1 = structure(list(col1 = c("123001 124003 125699", "29238822 293831232 992922"
        ), col2 = c("348348 3493493 1230404 99930202", "348348 3493493 1230404 99930202"
        ), col3 = c("CAT ODG JIN", "BAT MOUSE ANIME")), .Names = c("col1", 
        "col2", "col3"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")

sample2 = structure(list(id = c(123001L, 99930202L, 124003L, 1230404L, 
        29238822L, 293831232L, 3493493L, 125699L, 992922L, 348348L), 
            text = c("CAT", "PIG", "ODG", "CHAIN", "BAT", "MOUSE", "KIWI", 
            "JIN", "ANIME", "UPPE")), .Names = c("id", "text"), row.names = c(NA, 
        -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: That's a nice solution using a one-liner with base R to convert one column. How would you apply this solution to convert a data frame with many columns (more than the 2 columns in the OP)?

Answer (score 1):

There might be duplicates to this question on SO but I haven't spent much time on googling.

You may try this solution using `melt` and `dcast` from the `data.table` package:

```
molten <- melt(Sample1, measure.vars = c("col1", "col2"))
splitted <- molten[, strsplit(value, " "), by = .(rowid(variable), variable)]
splitted[, V1  := as.integer(V1)]
joined <- Sample2[splitted, on = c(id = "V1")]
dcast(joined, rowid ~ variable, paste, collapse = " ", value.var = c("id", "text"))
#   rowid                   id_col1                         id_col2       text_col1
#1:     1      123001 124003 125699 348348 3493493 1230404 99930202     CAT ODG JIN
#2:     2 29238822 293831232 992922 348348 3493493 1230404 99930202 BAT MOUSE ANIME
#             text_col2
#1: UPPE KIWI CHAIN PIG
#2: UPPE KIWI CHAIN PIG
```

This approach is independent of the number of columns in `Sample1` and also independent of the size of the set of numbers in each cell.

**Data**

```
Sample1 <-
structure(list(col1 = c("123001 124003 125699", "29238822 293831232 992922"
), col2 = c("348348 3493493 1230404 99930202", "348348 3493493 1230404 99930202"
)), .Names = c("col1", "col2"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
Sample2 <-
structure(list(id = c(123001L, 99930202L, 124003L, 1230404L, 
29238822L, 293831232L, 3493493L, 125699L, 992922L, 348348L), 
    text = c("CAT", "PIG", "ODG", "CHAIN", "BAT", "MOUSE", "KIWI", 
    "JIN", "ANIME", "UPPE")), .Names = c("id", "text"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```